# How to perform erase operation of certain range of the data structure?

Tags: c++, hashmap, c++17, big-o

Let's say I have a map used as a data structure, and it has a predefined n number of elements, I would like to know if there is a way to erase the sub-range of elements of that map in O(log n) time at most.
the reason I'm asking is that I want to implement `assign()` function that would overwrite the current sub-range of the map.

So far I have my template class that has the `assign()` function, where I have attempted to implement the logic, however, what I get is O(log N + K) mainly due to `erase()`, and I was wondering if there is any better way?

```
void assign(K const &keyBegin, K const &keyEnd, V const &val)
    {
        if (!(keyBegin < keyEnd))
            return;

        auto [iend, endAdded] = m_map.emplace(keyEnd, val);

        auto eraseEnd = iend;
        if (endAdded)
        {

            const auto &vprev = (iend == std::begin(m_map) ? m_valBegin : std::prev(iend)->second);
            if (vprev == val)
            {
                eraseEnd = std::next(iend);
            }
            else
            {
                iend->second = vprev;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (iend->second == val)
            {
                eraseEnd = std::next(iend);
            }
        }

        auto ibeg = m_map.insert_or_assign(iend, keyBegin, val);
        auto eraseBeg = std::next(ibeg);
        {
            const auto &vprev = (ibeg == std::begin(m_map) ? m_valBegin : std::prev(ibeg)->second);
            if (vprev == val)
                eraseBeg = ibeg;
        }

        m_map.erase(eraseBeg, eraseEnd);
    }
```

Comment: If a data structure holds objects with non-trivial destructors, removing a range of elements requires destroying each element. That's inherently O(N).

Comment: @PeteBecker is there a possible workaround?

Comment: Not really. You have N items. Each of those N items must be visited (destroyed).

Comment: The `hashmap` tag is irrelevant here, because a hashmap has no predefined or guaranteed ordering. Therefore there is no notion of a “range” in such a container. You can remove elements by performing e.g. a set intersections on the keys, which takes at least O(`n`) where `n` is the number of keys removed. Removing a range from an ordered tree map (such as `std::map`) costs at least O(`n` log(`N`)) where `n` is the size of the removed range and `N` is the size of the original map. Only special cases (e.g. maps with integral keys from a narrow enough range) could achieve O(`n`) range removals.